# 'nohup' command is not working with 'watch' command

Tags: nohup, watch-command

I have tried to run `nohup watch -n 5 python3 main.py &` but it is not working anymore. Is there any way to run `watch -n 5 python3 main.py &` command in background?

Answer (score 0):

You could just run it in a tmux or screen session and leave it there. Or write a small upstart script fx

```
description "main"
author ""
start on filesystem and net-device-up IFACE!=lo

exec python3 main.py
```

and let the main.py handle the iteration.